# How to determine which scene is the current by using Swift syntax?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, detect, scene

I have two scenes that need to be scrolled up when the keyboard appears. It works fine when I only need one scene to do so. Technically, I think, I need a judgement statement in ViewController.swift to determine which scene is on right now. For example:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    // if current scene is scene_A, do this on scene_A
    {
    ScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 220), animated: true)
    }

    //else if current scene is scene_b, do this on scene_B
    {
    scroll.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 200), animated: true)
    }
```

Or, if you have even smarter way to solve this, please tell me. Big, big help here. I've been stuck for hours. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by scene?

Comment: You must add some come, explain also if you use spriteKit..

Comment: "scene" I mean view controller, like the artboard in Sketch, is the screen view.

Comment: HI Alessandro, I don't use spriteKit. Would you please give me an example of the "come" you mentioned? Thank you.